# Imread openCV can not read image in windows

Tags: python, opencv

I am runnning some test on my local windows and I just came up with couple of lines of codes to read an image from my windows drive but it appears it can not read the image

```
input_arr = cv2.imread("C:\Downloads\database\Imagens_e_Matrizes_da_Tese_de_Thiago_Alves_Elias_da_Silva\Desenvolvimento_da_Metodologia\SAUDÁVEIS\1000\Segmentadas\PAC_38_DN0-dir.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
input_arr
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what is wrong with my codes?

The path. Windows uses backslashes, that must be escaped via `\\`. Personally, though, I prefer r-strings:

```
cv2.imread(r"C:\Downloads\database\Imagens_e_Matrizes_da_Tese_de_Thiago_Alves_Elias_da_Silva\Desenvolvimento_da_Metodologia\SAUDÁVEIS\1000\Segmentadas\PAC_38_DN0-dir.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
#          ^
```

(note the `r"` in the beginning)

**Note:** Windows also hates unicode characters. As it happens, in this case, together with the missing escaping, there's also a problem with the folder `SAUDÁVEIS`.

Comment: It is strange, no matter I put r in the begging, it doesn't read image from the path!

Comment: You're sure the image exists at the path, right? Another possible reason could be if the image is damaged or truncated, but that's more unlikely

Comment: Also, just to be extra sure, try copying the image to a path that doesn't have non-ascii characters (the subfolder `SAUDÁVEIS` might be problematic because of the accent)

Answer (score 0):

add **r** before beginning of path

```
input_arr=cv2.imread(r"C:\Downloads\database\Imagens_e_Matrizes_da_Tese_de_Thiago_Alves_Elias_da_Silva\Desenvolvimento_da_Metodologia\SAUDÁVEIS\1000\Segmentadas\PAC_38_DN0-dir.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```